# Using - instead of _ in filenames

Tags: filenames

I am a fresher and my TL told me to use '-' instead of '_' in filenames like

```
file-name.php instead of file_name.php
```

But he didn't told me why. He said that it is rule, but it sounded funny to me.

Can anybody tell me the main reason behind it??

Thanks

Comment: I'd ask him for the reason why!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a very strong reason, certainly not so much that one would call it a *rule*, but there is a reason you might use hyphens.

When Google sees words separated by hyphens, it treats them as separate words, when they are separated by underscores it doesn't. Or at least, [that was the case back in 2006](http://blog.codinghorror.com/of-spaces-underscores-and-dashes/) and I don't know that it has changed since.

So there is no effect on your actual code, but there is an effect on how your site is indexed, which affects how useful your code will be in terms of users being able to find it.

You could of course use routing to work around the urls anyway - indeed you probably will in most real-world work - at which point it comes down to personal preference once more.

Comment: Oh yes, I understood it. When we double click on any text separated by underscore the whole word will be selected, but when we double click on text separated by hyphen only the word before hyphen will select.